# Keycloak migration fails with liquibase.exception.DatabaseException. Using MariaDB and trying to understand the liquibase changelog (NCLOB)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, installation

We recently upgraded our Keycloak server from 18 to 20.

We mostly use MySQL, but for this particular instance we use MariaDB. Keycloak is built using `KC_DB=mysql`, if that matters here.

Now after startup in the new environment we get this error message:

```
Setting up realm configuration
Importing realm and user in case they don't exist yet
2022-11-12 09:08:10,439 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: hostname.com, Strict HTTPS: true, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: -1, Proxied: true
2022-11-12 09:08:11,815 WARN  [io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources] (main) Datasource <default> enables XA but transaction recovery is not enabled. Please enable transaction recovery by setting quarkus.transaction-manager.enable-recovery=true, otherwise data may be lost if the application is terminated abruptly
2022-11-12 09:08:12,482 WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
2022-11-12 09:08:12,581 WARN  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
2022-11-12 09:08:12,643 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller'
2022-11-12 09:08:12,998 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Triskaidekaphobia' 13.0.10.Final
2022-11-12 09:08:13,073 WARN  [liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory] (main) Unknown database: MySQL
2022-11-12 09:08:14,159 WARN  [liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory] (main) Unknown database: MySQL
2022-11-12 09:08:14,183 WARN  [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.CustomLockDatabaseChangeLogGenerator] (main) No direct support for database liquibase.database.core.UnsupportedDatabase . Database lock may not work correctly
2022-11-12 09:08:14,184 WARN  [liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory] (main) Unknown database: MySQL
2022-11-12 09:08:14,283 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.storage.legacy.liquibase.QuarkusJpaUpdaterProvider] (main) Updating database. Using changelog META-INF/jpa-changelog-master.xml
2022-11-12 09:08:14,780 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (import_export) mode
2022-11-12 09:08:14,781 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to update database
2022-11-12 09:08:14,781 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-20.0.0.xml::client-attributes-string-accomodation-fixed::keycloak:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 [Failed SQL: (1064) ALTER TABLE CLIENT_ATTRIBUTES ADD VALUE_NEW CLOB]
2022-11-12 09:08:14,781 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-20.0.0.xml::client-attributes-string-accomodation-fixed::keycloak:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 [Failed SQL: (1064) ALTER TABLE CLIENT_ATTRIBUTES ADD VALUE_NEW CLOB]
2022-11-12 09:08:14,781 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 [Failed SQL: (1064) ALTER TABLE CLIENT_ATTRIBUTES ADD VALUE_NEW CLOB]
2022-11-12 09:08:14,781 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
2022-11-12 09:08:14,781 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.
```

I understand the 'broken' line is:

```
ALTER TABLE CLIENT_ATTRIBUTES ADD VALUE_NEW CLOB
```

According to the MariaDB docs, `CLOB` is supported only when  `sql_mode=oracle`. Fine, we don't use oracle `sql_mode` so I tried to change it to `oracle`. I did this on a DB level and I understand there is also a global level, which I haven't touched.

No success. After startup the same message.

So I started looking at the [changelog](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/20.0.0/model/jpa/src/main/resources/META-INF/jpa-changelog-20.0.0.xml) and here it shows `NCLOB` instead of `CLOB`, but I don't find anything documented regarding the `NCLOB`.

Any ideas what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case, we set the DB upgrade to the manual to get all the queries keycloak needs to do,
then instead of creating a VALUE_NEW column with a requested type, we change the type of VALUE manually and insert the new data into the column.

Also, the new type for us was TEXT

Comment: Unfortunately we ended up doing the same.

Answer (score 4):

I encoutered this issue while upgrading from keycloak 15 to 21

I fixed it simply by replacing `mysql`by `mariadb`in `conf/keycloak.conf`

```
# The database vendor.
db=mariadb

# The full database JDBC URL. If not provided, a default URL is set based on the selected database vendor.
db-url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/keycloak?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC
```